# Bash equivalent of sed command

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script in bash and i would like to know if there is an alternative way to write these sed commands (without using sed):

```
sed '1,11d;$d' "${SOTTOCARTELLA}"/file
sed '1,11!d' "${SOTTOCARTELLA}"/file
sed '1,11d' -i "${SOTTOCARTELLA}"/file1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that `sed` isn't doing for you? If I read those commands correctly you can easily achieve the same with `head` and `tail`, but I don't know why you wouldn't use a working solution.

Comment: I know that this works, i am just curios about if there is an equivalent that can produce the same result as these sed commands i posted here. How could it be done with head and tail? thanks!

Comment: If you are using `head` and `tail`, that's not `bash`!

Answer (score 1):

With `sed '1,11!d' "${SOTTOCARTELLA}"/file` you are asking for the first 11 lines of the file;

With `sed '1,11d' -i "${SOTTOCARTELLA}"/file1` you are asking for the entire file except for the first 11 lines.

If you don't want to use `head`, `tail` or other binaries as suggested, you can achieve the same options using `read` and some support variables.

For example, let's try `sed '1,11!d' "${SOTTOCARTELLA}"/file`.
You will need a start point and an end point (and of course, the file).

```
start=1
end=11
counter="$((start - 1))";
file="${SOTTOCARTELLA}/file"
exec 3<"${file}" ### Create file descriptor 3
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do ### Read file line by line
  if [ "${counter}" -lt "${end}" ]; then ### If I'm in my "bundaries"
    printf "%s\n" "${line}" ### Print the line
  fi
  counter="$((counter + 1))"
done
exec 3>&- ### Close file descriptor 3
```

Note that this piece of code can be way better (E.G. adding a control on the counter in while  condition), but this is the least you will need to understand two things:

- `sed`, `head`, `tails`, `awk`, etc. are born in order to avoid to rewrite over and over again same routines and, also, for performance issues; this is why everyone, including me, will be telling you to use those.
- This kind of codes are useful only for portability concerns, that's why I wrote this piece of code in a posix compliant way.